# What about using LINQ or Yield Return in for loops?

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop, xna, yield

Currently I'm working on a 2D XNA game. It needs optimizing, because the multiplayer mode is not performing well. In code we have mostly used foreach loops, and have not used LINQ or yield return statements anywhere. I understand we can win some performance here. Since for loops are faster, I was thinking of replacing all foreach loops.

**But, however, I can't benefit from the yield return statement in a for loop, can I?

Also, will LINQ still be useful when iterating using a for loop?**

---

For example, I have a list of 1000+ shapes (squares, triangles, circles...), and I want to enumerate through all squares (75%) at a certain position. What's the best way of doing this?
What should I use? Arrays, lists, for loops, foreach loops, yield return and/or LINQ?

Comment: you can use LINQ to find these squares and then use  foreach loop to return these squers

Comment: *Before* you do any optimizing, *measure* where your bottlenecks are. Are you sure that this loop is the bottleneck?

Comment: @Heinzi: Well, there is a certain list that is used in a lot of places (with foreach). I'm already busy finding ways to reduce the usage of this list, but while I'm busy I thought maybe it is time to learn a little bit more about LINQ, yield and for loops.

Comment: Is parallelization methods an option for speeding up processing of large collections? It adds alot more code, but will in return speed up things.

Comment: Do you need do group the different types somehow? in that case you can use dictionary with the type as a key and a list of squares for example as a value.

Comment: @StianStandahl: is iterating a Dictionary faster? And can you provide me a link about "parellelization methods"?

Comment: Absolutely not, but if you want to group the types. for example {square, [square1, square2, ..]}. It could be faster to have all the types grouped and in memory for do a fast retrieval of wanted types. The dictionary could look something like this Dictionary<Type, List<GraphicBase>>

Comment: @StianStandahl, good point - making iteration faster is not necessary right approach - reducing number of items to iterate/reducing need for iteration will provide much better results than any other optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do any grouping or sorting you need to do as items are added, not as they are retrieved. I say this because you'll (I assume) only add each item once, but as you say you're retrieving them multiple times.

Comment: It sounds like I need to group my lists by type. However, sometimes I need a list of all objects, not type-specific. How would you solve that?

Comment: In that case I'd add them all to a master collection as well. That will add very minimal overhead since you're essentially just adding an extra collection of pointers rather than cloning objects.

Comment: In good old days of asm and 3d demos the fastest way by far was to create lookup lists of items you want to retrieve. Sure memory footprint goes up a little but it's reference pointers you are storing.

Answer (score 4):

Since it is performance question the only right answer is measure.

In general directly using `for` will likely be the fastest approach as the rest add more code for each iteration. Try and measure yourself - see if it matters in your case and which version of code you like to read the most.

Comment: But will LINQ still be beneficial? Should I still use LINQ's `OfType<T>` beforehand? Or should I just check types inside the for loop?

Comment: I would be very careful using any LINQ statements inside of your game loop.  It's very easy to accidentally create garbage using LINQ, and that can kill your game's performance.  If you do use a LINQ statement, be certain that it isn't boxing objects or creating arrays somewhere under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use `For` loop. If not for the performance gain, which will be negligible, you will not create enumerator object. So you don't put unnecessary pressure on GC.

Comment: Many of the built-in collections use mutable structs as their enumerator objects, so no pressure is put on the GC by using them inside of `foreach` loops.